# Automatically publishing maven project from eclipse doens't publish maven dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, publish

These are the steps I followed:

1. Created a maven project in eclipse.
2. Converted the project into faceted form.
3. Added the project to the server.

Now whenever I make any changes to my project resources, it gets reflected in server. But my WEB-INF/lib directory doesn't contain any maven dependency jar files.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed m2e integration for WTP and now it is copying the maven dependecies jars into WEB-INF/lib of the server installed apps directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse WTP, Maven dependencies are provided by WTP to the application server using some kind of special classpath container (as you see it in your project in Eclipse). So they are not copied to `WEB-INF/lib` directory but rather somehow "injected" by the WTP extension. But if you build Maven artifact (`mvn package`) everything should be OK.